# What is the right approach to insert multiple id's of petitions to single user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**I am very open to edits of the title**

Basically I am making a site about petitions. I want a user to be able to sign more than one petitions and be able to see list of petitions he signed. I am wondering what is the right approach to do it.

**Approach 1 that I thought of:**
Every petition has a unique id and every user has a unique id. To my petitions table I could add a varchar column named "signedUsers" and there I could add users id with a ',', then pull it out as a string, separate it by ',' and display every petition a user has signed.

**Approach 2 that I thought of:**
Similar to the first one, with the difference that instead storing signed users to the petitions table, I could store "signedPetitions" to the users table.

Those are the approaches that I can think of, but it's my first time doing it and I don't know if there is "known" or "common" approach to such situations, so I am open to some enlightenment.

**P.S.**
Not sure if this is the proper place to ask question without code, so I am sorry if it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a table `userPetitions` with one row per user and one row per petition.  This table would have a user id and petition id, with foreign key relationships back to those tables.

This is called a *junction table* or *association table* and is the right way to store many-to-many relationships in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be a association table `signature`.
Each signature would be registered in a separate row.

- One column for the `user_id`
- One column for the `petition_id`

If you need additional info for the user, put it in a `user` table primary key: `user_id`.
If you need additional info for the petition, put it in a `petition` table with primary key: `petition_id`.